# Unable to SSH into Windows Domain server using Domain User

Tags: windows, ssh

On our Windows Server 2019 is Open SSH Installed
Versions used/tested:

- OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
- OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.9.2

Logon to the Server with a **local account** (the account exists on the server) **works well**: 
`ssh user@host`

Logon to the Server with a **domain account** (the account exists on the domain) is **not possible**:
`ssh domain\\user@host`
or
`ssh user@domain@host`

Message on the client is:
`Connection reset by 10.70.108.76 port 22`

**Anybody an idea how to fix or at least debug this issue ???**

I read guides about installing OpenSSH-Server : 
e.g. [Install OpenSSH | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)

On the Server I noticed these Logs

**Server -> Event-Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Security** : 
`Audit Failure`
`Failure Reason:        Unknown user name or bad password`

**Server -> Event-Viewer -> Applications and Services logs > OpenSSH > Admin**

`sshd: fatal: ga_init, unable to resolve user domain\\user`
`sshd: error: get_user_token - unable to generate token on 2nd attempt for user domain\\user`

Verbose output -vvv prints this message before disconnecting :

**debug3: recv - from CB ERROR:10054, io:0000026B5723BCD0**
**Connection reset by 192.168.0.1 port 22**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by missing AD (Active Directory) Groups / AD Privileges

**After granting the Computer to read all properties of the user which wants to connect via SSH :
 Open ActiveDirectory > User > Properties > Add > (OpenSSH)Server > Read (is already checked after adding)**

[image]

**it works!**

Also there is another thread describing something very similar : [Domain user authentication fails with Connection Reset by Peer](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1363)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ssh -l user@domain.com hostname
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to enter the username like this:

```
ssh user:domain@host
```

Bare in mind: case sensitive!

Comment: For the user i am able to log-in the case does NOT matter